# The distribution of $tr(W)$, where $W$ is the standard Wishart-matrix.

Tags: matrices, statistics, normal-distribution, trace

Let $W  \sim \mathcal{W}_p(n, I_p) (I_p$ denodes the $p \times p$ identity matrix$)$ be a $p \times p$ standard Wishart-matrix ,$n > p$.

Determine the distribution of $tr(W)$!

From the definition, if the $C$ covariance matrix is the identity matrix, then this matix is called standard Wishart-matrix, where

$$W=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i X_i^T$$ and $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$, where $X_1,...,X_n \sim \mathcal{N}_p(0,C), C > 0$.

I have no idea how should I approach the trace of this matrix, and how to tell anything about it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You haven't googled enough ! There is a lot of literature on the subject.  Take a look for example to (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311831118_Trace_of_the_Wishart_Matrix_and_Applications).

Comment: I have checked this article, but not sure which part of it is which I require. Can you help me out? :)